# parallelized deep reinforcement learning

Tags: machine-learning, parallel-processing, gpu, reinforcement-learning

I am try to run DRL on a low speed environment and sequential learning is making me upset. is there anyway to speed up the learning process? I tried some offline deep reinforcement learning but I still need higher speed (if possible).

Comment: Three ways, you can, A) Get better hardware B) Write better software or C) Do better data science and select fewer features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Vectorized Environments](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/vec_envs.html). They will allow parallel interaction with your environments.

Comment: Thank you @tnfru , I also learned about the A3C, so how A3C could be different from vectorized env?

Comment: A3C is a model free algorithm. This doesn't have to do anything specific with using vectorized envs.